# php: Using <form> tag to sum a new value to an existing value in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am creating a webpage that is similar to a points system. It consists of a table with name and points columns. The user inputs a number, which then adds that value to the existing number in the table. My question is how would I be able to add those two values and update the table(database)?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("xxx, xxx, xxx);
if (!$con) {
die("can not connect:" . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("points", $con);

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE coach_tbl set coachscore = coachscore + '$add' WHERE coach_score = '$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO coach_tbl (coach_name, coach_score) VALUES('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[score]')";
    mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);   

};
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coach_tbl ORDER BY coach_score DESC";

echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";

$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo "<form action=index.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=coachname value='" . $record['coach_name'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=coachscore value='" . $record['coach_score'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['coach_score'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=submit name=update value=update'" . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=number min="1" max="10" name=add value=add'" . "'> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";

    }
echo "</table>";



mysql_close($con);

?>
```

If there are any questions I will gladly elaborate on anything. I am also fairly new to php.

Comment: I have two columns, the first one consists of names and the second consists of points. There are approximately 30 rows in that same format.

Comment: The question is quite vague but if you are looking to add the value typed by the user to an already existing value in the database you could just use SQL. `UPDATE point_table SET points = points + 10 WHERE id = 1;`

Comment: You missed a closing `"` in `$con = mysql_connect("xxx, xxx, xxx);` by the way.

Comment: OK I understand you. What if I wanted to have a user input a value, which then adds that value to the points already registered in the table? @Kepoly

Comment: Good looking out, thanks for the pointer @Peter !

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that's what you wanted, I can always tweak it to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an html form like so:

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
<input type="number" name="updateData" value=""/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and an update.php:

```
<?php 
//assuming you want 1-10 points max to be added each time
if( isset($_POST['updateData']) && $_POST['updateData'] >=1  && $_POST['updateData'] >=10){

 //set to user inputed value
$insertData = $_POST['updateData'];

$sql = "UPDATE point_table SET points = points + $insertData WHERE id = 1";
//you will need to finish off the query by checking connecting with your database.
}

?>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I managed to tweak it here and there. but it worked out at the end. Thanks for your help! @kepoly